# UpSet plot with Altair 5.2

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to reproduce this interesting chart with Altair 5.2 (and python 3.11.5):

https://upset.app/implementations/#UpSetAltair
https://github.com/hms-dbmi/upset-altair-notebook

And I believe Altair has some changes with parameters relative to version 4, which seems to be what that example was programmed in:
https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html

I am receiving this error, which I am not quite sure how to troubleshoot, and unless I am looking in wrong place, I don't find additional information in the javascript console:

```
Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "param_1_tuple"
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.
```

program is:

```py
# %%
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

alt.__version__

# %%
# Use the latest data from https://figshare.com/articles/covid_symptoms_table_csv/12148893
df = pd.read_csv("https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/22339791")

df.head()


# %%
# Top-level altair configuration
def upsetaltair_top_level_configuration(
    base, legend_orient="top-left", legend_symbol_size=30
):
    return (
        base.configure_view(stroke=None)
        .configure_title(
            fontSize=18, fontWeight=400, anchor="start", subtitlePadding=10
        )
        .configure_axis(
            labelFontSize=14,
            labelFontWeight=300,
            titleFontSize=16,
            titleFontWeight=400,
            titlePadding=10,
        )
        .configure_legend(
            titleFontSize=16,
            titleFontWeight=400,
            labelFontSize=14,
            labelFontWeight=300,
            padding=20,
            orient=legend_orient,
            symbolType="circle",
            symbolSize=legend_symbol_size,
        )
        .configure_concat(spacing=0)
    )


# %%
def UpSetAltair(
    data=None,
    title="",
    subtitle="",
    sets=None,
    abbre=None,
    sort_by="frequency",
    sort_order="ascending",
    width=1200,
    height=700,
    height_ratio=0.6,
    horizontal_bar_chart_width=300,
    color_range=["#55A8DB", "#3070B5", "#30363F", "#F1AD60", "#DF6234", "#BDC6CA"],
    highlight_color="#EA4667",
    glyph_size=200,
    set_label_bg_size=1000,
    line_connection_size=2,
    horizontal_bar_size=20,
    vertical_bar_label_size=16,
    vertical_bar_padding=20,
):
    data["count"] = 0
    data = data[sets + ["count"]]
    data = data.groupby(sets).count().reset_index()

    data["intersection_id"] = data.index
    data["degree"] = data[sets].sum(axis=1)
    data = data.sort_values(
        by=["count"], ascending=True if sort_order == "ascending" else False
    )

    data = pd.melt(data, id_vars=["intersection_id", "count", "degree"])
    data = data.rename(columns={"variable": "set", "value": "is_intersect"})

    if abbre == None:
        abbre = sets

    set_to_abbre = pd.DataFrame(
        [[sets[i], abbre[i]] for i in range(len(sets))], columns=["set", "set_abbre"]
    )

    set_to_order = pd.DataFrame(
        [[sets[i], 1 + sets.index(sets[i])] for i in range(len(sets))],
        columns=["set", "set_order"],
    )

    degree_calculation = ""
    for s in sets:
        degree_calculation += f"(isDefined(datum['{s}']) ? datum['{s}'] : 0)"
        if sets[-1] != s:
            degree_calculation += "+"

    """
    Selections
    """
    legend_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=["set"], bind="legend")
    color_selection = alt.selection_point(
        fields=["intersection_id"], on="mouseover", nearest=True
    )
    opacity_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=["intersection_id"])

    """
    Styles
    """
    vertical_bar_chart_height = height * height_ratio
    matrix_height = height - vertical_bar_chart_height
    matrix_width = width - horizontal_bar_chart_width

    vertical_bar_size = min(
        30,
        width / len(data["intersection_id"].unique().tolist()) - vertical_bar_padding,
    )

    main_color = "#3A3A3A"
    brush_opacity = alt.condition(~opacity_selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.6))
    brush_color = alt.condition(
        ~color_selection, alt.value(main_color), alt.value(highlight_color)
    )

    is_show_horizontal_bar_label_bg = len(abbre[0]) <= 2
    horizontal_bar_label_bg_color = (
        "white" if is_show_horizontal_bar_label_bg else "black"
    )

    x_sort = alt.Sort(
        field="count" if sort_by == "frequency" else "degree", order=sort_order
    )
    tooltip = [
        alt.Tooltip("max(count):Q", title="Cardinality"),
        alt.Tooltip("degree:Q", title="Degree"),
    ]

    """
    Plots
    """
    # To use native interactivity in Altair, we are using the data transformation functions
    # supported in Altair.
    base = (
        alt.Chart(data)
        .transform_filter(legend_selection)
        .transform_pivot(
            # Right before this operation, columns should be:
            # `count`, `set`, `is_intersect`, (`intersection_id`, `degree`, `set_order`, `set_abbre`)
            # where (fields with brackets) should be dropped and recalculated later.
            "set",
            op="max",
            groupby=["intersection_id", "count"],
            value="is_intersect",
        )
        .transform_aggregate(
            # count, set1, set2, ...
            count="sum(count)",
            groupby=sets,
        )
        .transform_calculate(
            # count, set1, set2, ...
            degree=degree_calculation
        )
        .transform_filter(
            # count, set1, set2, ..., degree
            alt.datum["degree"]
            != 0
        )
        .transform_window(
            # count, set1, set2, ..., degree
            intersection_id="row_number()",
            frame=[None, None],
        )
        .transform_fold(
            # count, set1, set2, ..., degree, intersection_id
            sets,
            as_=["set", "is_intersect"],
        )
        .transform_lookup(
            # count, set, is_intersect, degree, intersection_id
            lookup="set",
            from_=alt.LookupData(set_to_abbre, "set", ["set_abbre"]),
        )
        .transform_lookup(
            # count, set, is_intersect, degree, intersection_id, set_abbre
            lookup="set",
            from_=alt.LookupData(set_to_order, "set", ["set_order"]),
        )
        .transform_filter(
            # Make sure to remove the filtered sets.
            legend_selection
        )
        .transform_window(
            # count, set, is_intersect, degree, intersection_id, set_abbre
            set_order="distinct(set)",
            frame=[None, 0],
            sort=[{"field": "set_order"}],
        )
        .add_params(legend_selection)
    )
    # Now, we have data in the following format:
    # count, set, is_intersect, degree, intersection_id, set_abbre

    # Cardinality by intersecting sets (vertical bar chart)
    vertical_bar = (
        base.mark_bar(color=main_color, size=vertical_bar_size).encode(
            x=alt.X(
                "intersection_id:N",
                axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, labels=False, ticks=False, domain=True),
                sort=x_sort,
                title=None,
            ),
            y=alt.Y(
                "max(count):Q",
                axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, tickCount=3, orient="right"),
                title="Intersection Size",
            ),
            color=brush_color,
            tooltip=tooltip,
        )
        # .add_params(color_selection)
        .properties(width=matrix_width, height=vertical_bar_chart_height)
    )

    vertical_bar_text = vertical_bar.mark_text(
        color=main_color, dy=-10, size=vertical_bar_label_size
    ).encode(text=alt.Text("count:Q", format=".0f"))

    vertical_bar_chart = (vertical_bar + vertical_bar_text).add_params(color_selection)

    # UpSet glyph view (matrix view)
    circle_bg = (
        vertical_bar.mark_circle(size=glyph_size, opacity=1)
        .encode(
            x=alt.X(
                "intersection_id:N",
                axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, labels=False, ticks=False, domain=False),
                sort=x_sort,
                title=None,
            ),
            y=alt.Y(
                "set_order:N",
                axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, labels=False, ticks=False, domain=False),
                title=None,
            ),
            color=alt.value("#E6E6E6"),
        )
        .properties(height=matrix_height)
        # .add_params(color_selection)
    )

    rect_bg = (
        circle_bg.mark_rect()
        .transform_filter(alt.datum["set_order"] % 2 == 1)
        .encode(color=alt.value("#F7F7F7"))
    ).properties(height=matrix_height)

    circle = (
        circle_bg.transform_filter(alt.datum["is_intersect"] == 1)
        .encode(color=brush_color)
        .properties(height=matrix_height)
        # .add_params(color_selection)
    )

    line_connection = (
        (
            vertical_bar.mark_bar(size=line_connection_size, color=main_color)
            .transform_filter(alt.datum["is_intersect"] == 1)
            .encode(y=alt.Y("min(set_order):N"), y2=alt.Y2("max(set_order):N"))
        ).properties(height=matrix_height)
        # .add_params(color_selection)
    )

    matrix_view = (rect_bg + circle + circle_bg + line_connection).add_params(
        color_selection
    )

    # matrix_view = (circle + rect_bg + circle_bg + line_connection + circle).add_params(
    #     # Duplicate `circle` is to properly show tooltips.
    #     color_selection
    # )

    # Cardinality by sets (horizontal bar chart)
    # horizontal_bar_label_bg = base.mark_circle(size=set_label_bg_size).encode(
    #     y=alt.Y(
    #         "set_order:N",
    #         axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, labels=False, ticks=False, domain=False),
    #         title=None,
    #     ),
    #     color=alt.Color(
    #         "set:N", scale=alt.Scale(domain=sets, range=color_range), title=None
    #     ),
    #     opacity=alt.value(1),
    # )

    # horizontal_bar_label = horizontal_bar_label_bg.mark_text(
    #     align=("center" if is_show_horizontal_bar_label_bg else "center")
    # ).encode(
    #     text=alt.Text("set_abbre:N"), color=alt.value(horizontal_bar_label_bg_color)
    # )

    # horizontal_bar_axis = (
    #     (horizontal_bar_label_bg + horizontal_bar_label)
    #     if is_show_horizontal_bar_label_bg
    #     else horizontal_bar_label
    # )

    # horizontal_bar = (
    #     horizontal_bar_label_bg.mark_bar(size=horizontal_bar_size)
    #     .transform_filter(alt.datum["is_intersect"] == 1)
    #     .encode(
    #         x=alt.X(
    #             "sum(count):Q", axis=alt.Axis(grid=False, tickCount=3), title="Set Size"
    #         )
    #     )
    #     .properties(width=horizontal_bar_chart_width)
    # )

    # Concat Plots
    # upsetaltair = alt.vconcat(
    #     vertical_bar_chart,
    #     alt.hconcat(
    #         matrix_view,
    #         horizontal_bar_axis,
    #         horizontal_bar,  # horizontal bar chart
    #         spacing=5,
    #     ).resolve_scale(y="shared"),
    #     spacing=20,
    # ).add_selection(legend_selection)

    # # Apply top-level configuration
    # upsetaltair = upsetaltair_top_level_configuration(
    #     upsetaltair, legend_orient="top", legend_symbol_size=set_label_bg_size / 2.0
    # ).properties(
    #     title={
    #         "text": title,
    #         "subtitle": subtitle,
    #         "fontSize": 20,
    #         "fontWeight": 500,
    #         "subtitleColor": main_color,
    #         "subtitleFontSize": 14,
    #     }
    # )

    return matrix_view


# %%
UpSetAltair(
    data=df,
    title="Symptoms Reported by Users of the COVID Symptom Tracker App",
    subtitle=[
        "Story & Data: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-00154-w",
        "Altair-based UpSet Plot: https://github.com/hms-dbmi/upset-altair-notebook",
    ],
    sets=["Shortness of Breath", "Diarrhea", "Fever", "Cough", "Anosmia", "Fatigue"],
    abbre=["B", "D", "Fe", "C", "A", "Fa"],
)

# %%
```

Comment: Are you able to break the spec down to a simpler version that reproduces the issue? It is likely that some chart with the same param are layered somewhere, as mentioned here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2159#issuecomment-630778929. Other potentially useful issues could be https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/8230 and https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/8168